# SQL Errors from OnSave EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a piece of code within EF Core which should insert 100+ rows into the destination table.

On purpose I have added an error, there is a column in SQL which is of type `Varchar(150)`. I have added more than that in a row - and yes I get the error but I do require the error for each row I insert into on the `OnSave`. Not just one error.

The SQL error is :

> String or binary data would be truncated in table 'Area_of_Expertise_Type', column 'Name'.
>
> Truncated value: 'gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg'.

So within code :

```
var AreaOfExpertiseType = new AreaOfExpertiseType
                {
                    AreaOfExpertiseTypeId = item.AreaofExpId,
                    Name = "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
                    Description = "Review Requirement for Description in CL"
                };

_clDBContext.AreaOfExpertiseType.Add(AreaOfExpertiseType);
               
try 
{
    _clDBContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
{
    // ErrList.Add(new ErrorList()
    //                 {
    //                     Error = ex.InnerException?.Message
    // });
    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException?.Message);
}
```

There is a for each above so I can add all the rows in. So as you can see I am trapping the `OnSave`.

Any ideas why I am only seeing one error? I want to get the id from the source database so I really need to see all the errors.

Comment: Where is the foreach ?

Comment: Execution halts in case of an error. If the 50th row falls in one SaveChanges() call, the transaction is rolled back and you won't get additional errors for the following rows. If you want per row error reporting, you gotta call SaveChanges() after each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To trigger an error per inserted row you will have to execute .SaveChanges() efter each insert, the insertion is processed as a transaction therefore it can only fail once.

It will be pretty inefficient to save for each row, generally i would advice against it.